# Better way to update an USB ISO without unplug

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, bios, operating-systems, iso-image

I'm working creating a small O.S. When I make changes, I create and ISO. This ISO works propertly with qemu, but when I have to test some hardware issues, I need to boot it on another computer. So:

1. I Plug an USB in my computer
2. I copy with dd the ISO to the USB *sudo
   dd if=my_os.iso of=/dev/sdb*
3. I unplug from my computer
4. I plug it in other computer, and reboot.

Bios launch propertly the new O.S compilation.

After 100 times every morning, this is frustrating. So I'm looking for a way to avoid unplug, launch dd script, etc.

I have explored use a way like SD card with wireless, [this tutorial](http://haxit.blogspot.com.es/2013/08/hacking-transcend-wifi-sd-cards.html) show how to change remotely a folder. I think this is not a solution because in essence, the card has a small linux-like OS to mount the data, and I need to override a part of the memory to be launched by the BIOS.

Another way I have explored is to use a raspberry pi, connected by USB (I don't know if its possible directly) and try to use a protocol like MTP to emulate the usb as memory, so I can create a script to send the new iso to raspberry, update the part of the memory with the iso, and switch on the other computer that load in RAM the new O.S compilation.

I have no more plans, and I'm thinking that is impossible, so, any ideas to solve this problem?

UPDATE: My problem is similar to [this post](https://flashair-developers.com/en/documents/tutorials/users/1/). I'm going to try to adapt it to this and avoid buy more hardware (Except a wifi SD)

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience so I can't help with logistics - but host the OS on your PC and network boot from the other?

Comment: 100 times every morning? I would suggest that you reconsider your approach to debugging.

Comment: @brydonGibson what do you mean exactly? I can debug using qemu and connecting gdb remotely, but in other computer, working with ethernet driver I can, at least right now

Comment: I was thinking the way a thin client or office computer works, there should be a network boot setting in your BIOS, and I believe the PC polls a server for an OS, not sure how the server is supposed to respond though

Comment: @Brydon Gibson Trying some net booting, it seems too complicated to my issue, http://www.howtogeek.com/57601/what-is-network-booting-pxe-and-how-can-you-use-it/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is surprising that no commercial offering targets this problem directly. 
Here are some things to investigate.

1. Use a kvm (keyboard/video/mouse) switch that has an extra usb port for,
   eg, cdrom. This arbitrary example
   [TK-222DVK](http://www.trendnet.com/products/KVM-2-Port-switch/TK-222DVK)
   claims to have *2 bonus USB share ports for storage devices or printers*.
   My understanding is that you can therefore switch a device between two host
   computers, but I may be wrong (no documentation on the subject). Note, your 2nd computer must be able to
   handle the usb device behind a hub.
2. If you have a long distance between your 2 computers, you could consider
   an ip-kvm, ie kvm over the network. A arbitrary example
   [lantronix-spider](http://www.lantronix.com/products/lantronix-spider/#docs-downloads) 
   says it provides *Virtual Media support*. 
   My understanding is that this allows your 2nd computer to see a usb cdrom
   device, the data for which comes over the network from a "share" on another
   computer. The user guide provides some information, but not enough to be
   definitive. I think I've seen similar devices that have a dedicated usb
   port and in that case the cdrom might not be behind a hub.
3. I'm not a hardware person, but someone mentioned the
   [TS3USB221A](http://www.ti.com/product/TS3USB221A) which is a
   *high-bandwidth switch specially designed for the switching of high-speed
   USB 2.0 signals*, between 2 paths. It comes in an [evaluation
   module](http://www.ti.com/tool/ts3usb221aevm) where I think you see 1 usb
   socket being switched between 2 other usb sockets. Although they refer to
   output switching, it says the device is bidirectional, so that may be
   irrelevant. You probably need to be a company to order this board.
4. There are many microcontrollers with usb capabilities. One that has been
   wrapped into something more appealing is the
   [pyboard](http://micropython.org/) which allows you to run python on the
   board, rather than C, making for simpler development. The pyboard has an
   sdcard slot and can appear as a mass storage device on the usb of your 2nd
   computer, but it also has several ttl-level serial ports, so you could
   attach an FTDI type of (ttl)serial-to-usb adaptor, and write some python to
   update the sdcard data by sending data over the serial link from your first
   computer.
5. You have looked at an sdcard with wifi. Another such card is the toshiba [flashair](https://flashair-developers.com/en/documents/). It seems very open for development and you may find it possible to do what you want with it.

Comment: Interesting, I want a simple solution, I have found this https://flashair-developers.com/en/documents/tutorials/users/1/ , after think about the solution, I will check your answer if I have no a better one.